# My servlet is throwing Exceptions

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to build a login panel, but when i try to call a method inside the model (CustomerDbUtil), from the controller (LoginController), it throws Exceptions. I'm somewhat new to JSP and i'm unable to debug it. The code along with the console output is shown below :

**Login form**

```
    <form action="LoginController" method="POST" id="login-form">

        <header class="text-center">
            <h2 class="font-light">Login</h2>
        </header>

        <input type="hidden" name="command" value="LOAD">

        <label>Username : </label>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="form-control" required /><br>

        <label>Password : </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" required /><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary" /><br><br>

        <span style="color:black">New users</span> <a href="user-register.jsp">Register here</a>

    </form>
```

**LoginController** (Controller class)

```
package com.loginpanel.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginController
 */

@WebServlet("/LoginController")
public class LoginController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Resource(name="jdbc/login_module")
    DataSource datasource;
    private CustomerDbUtil customerDbUtil;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {

            // Get the form data 
            String username = request.getParameter("username");
            String md5 = md5(request.getParameter("password"));

            Customer theCustomer = validate(username, md5); 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServletException(); // Throws this exception
        }

    }


    private Customer validate(String username, String md5) throws Exception {

        Customer theCustomer;
        System.out.println("inside validate"); // Gets printed in the console

        try {

            theCustomer = customerDbUtil.selectCustomer(username, md5); // Throws Exception at this statement
            System.out.println("inside try"); // Not printed in the console

            if(theCustomer==null) {
                return null;
            } 

        } catch(Exception e) {
                throw new ServletException();
        }
        return theCustomer;

    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // Redirect back to the login page as the url does not support direct page access
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("./");
        request.setAttribute("message", "You need to login first");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }



    // Hash the string to MD5
    private String md5(String str) throws Exception {

        String plainText = str;
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();

        if(plainText!=null) {
            MessageDigest mdAlgorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            mdAlgorithm.update(plainText.getBytes());

            byte[] digest = mdAlgorithm.digest();

            for (int i = 0; i < digest.length; i++) {
                plainText = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & digest[i]);

                if (plainText.length() < 2) {
                    plainText = "0" + plainText;
                }

                hexString.append(plainText);
            }
        }
        return hexString.toString();
    }

}
```

**CustomerDbUtil** (Model)

```
package com.loginpanel.web;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import javax.sql.DataSource;


public class CustomerDbUtil {
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public CustomerDbUtil(DataSource theDataSource) {
        dataSource = theDataSource;
    }

    public boolean addCustomer(Customer theCustomer) throws Exception {

        // Declare the DB objects
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement myStmt = null;
        boolean isExecuted = false;

        try{
            // Get the connection 
            con = dataSource.getConnection();

            // Write the SQL for adding a student
            String sql = "INSERT INTO customers ( "
                    + " first_name, last_name, username, md5, country) "
                    + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

            // Prepare the statement
            myStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

            // Add the params
            myStmt.setString(1, theCustomer.getCustomerFirstName());
            myStmt.setString(2, theCustomer.getCustomerLastName());
            myStmt.setString(3, theCustomer.getUsername());
            myStmt.setString(4, theCustomer.getMd5());
            myStmt.setString(5, theCustomer.getCountry());

            // Execute the SQL statement
            if(myStmt.execute()){
                isExecuted = true;
            } else {
                isExecuted = false;
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // Clear the JDBC objects
            close(con, myStmt, null);
        }
        return isExecuted;
    }


    public Customer selectCustomer(String user, String md) throws Exception {

        Customer theCustomer = null;

        // Get the connection
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement myStmt = null;
        ResultSet myRs = null;

        System.out.println("What??");

        try {

            con = dataSource.getConnection();

            // Write the SQL statement
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM login_module.customers WHERE username = ? AND md5 = ?";

            // Prepare the statement
            myStmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

            // Add the parameters
            myStmt.setString(1, user);
            myStmt.setString(2, md);

            // Execute the query
            myRs = myStmt.executeQuery();

            System.out.println("Hello");

            // Fetch the student details
            if(myRs.next()) {
                int customerId = myRs.getInt("customer_id");
                String firstName = myRs.getString("first_name");
                String lastName = myRs.getString("last_name");
                String user_name = myRs.getString("username");
                String md5 = myRs.getString("md5");
                String country = myRs.getString("country");

                // Create a customer object
                theCustomer = new Customer(customerId, firstName, lastName, user_name, md5, country);

            } else {
                throw new Exception("Could not find the customer");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            close(con, myStmt, myRs);
        }

        return theCustomer;

    }


    public void close(Connection conn, Statement stm, ResultSet rs) throws Exception{

        try{
            // Close the objects
            if(conn!=null) {
                conn.close();
            }
            if(stm!=null) {
                stm.close();
            }
            if(rs!=null) {
                rs.close();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public List<Customer> getCustomers() throws Exception{

        List<Customer> listCustomer = new ArrayList<>();

        Connection con = null;
        Statement myStmt = null;
        ResultSet myRs = null;

        try {

                // Get the connection
                con = dataSource.getConnection();

                // Create SQL statements
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM login_module.customers";

                // Prepare the statement
                myStmt = con.createStatement();

                // Execute the statement and store it into the ResultSet
                myRs = myStmt.executeQuery(sql);

                // Fetch the data one-by-one and add it to the list
                while(myRs.next()){
                    int id = myRs.getInt("customer_id");
                    String firstName = myRs.getString("first_name");
                    String lastName = myRs.getString("last_name");
                    String username = myRs.getString("username");
                    String md5 = myRs.getString("md5");
                    String country = myRs.getString("country");


                    Customer theCustomer = new Customer (id, firstName, lastName, username, md5, country);

                    // Add it to the list
                    listCustomer.add(theCustomer);

                }

            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

                // Close the connection objects
                close(con, myStmt, myRs );

            }

            // Return the list
            return listCustomer;


    }

}
```

**Error log**

```
inside validate
May 13, 2017 7:24:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.loginpanel.web.LoginController] in context with path [/loginpanel] threw exception [null] with root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException
    at com.loginpanel.web.LoginController.doGet(LoginController.java:38)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1504)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1460)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I don't know if i'm missing out something or doing it somewhat wrong. Please help. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I suspect your customerDbUtil is not property wired and as a result it's null while invocation.  In this line -> theCustomer = customerDbUtil.selectCustomer(username, md5); // Throws Exception at this statement.

Comment: @user3138997... But my eclipse does not popup a single warning or error, like method not found or something.

Comment: It's a runtime exception and not a compilation error. Try initializing customerDbUtil. CustomerDbUtil customerDbUtil = new customerDbUtil(datasource); (my mistake initially I had thought this is a Spring MVC)

Comment: Your `catch(Exception e) { throw new ServletException(); }` is the first problem - it means that all you can tell is "something went wrong". You should *at least* change this to throw `new ServletException(e)` so you can see the details of the original exception. I'd suggest catching more specific exceptions where possible though, and not declaring methods to throw just `Exception` unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: @user3138997... Thanks man!! Your solution worked. I initialized the customerDbUtil inside the init block and it worked! Thanks :)

Comment: great. you could consider up vote!

Answer (score 0):

You can inject spring bean to your servlet.

```
ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContex t(getServletContext());
InterfaceType bean = (InterfaceType)context.getBean("BeanName");
```